# How to prove the correct decryption of several (ElGamal) ciphertexts in a batch？

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption

I know how to prove the correct decryption of a (ElGamal) ciphertext.
[image]

The above protocol is from the paper: Bootle J, Cerulli A, Chaidos P, et al. Short accountable ring signatures based on DDH[C]//European Symposium on Research in Computer Security. Cham: Springer International Publishing, 2015: 243-265.

But,how to prove the correct decryption of several (ElGamal) ciphertexts in a batch? Performing the above protocol for each ciphertext seems inefficient.

Comment: For example, there are some ciphertexts {C1, C2, C3, ...., Cn}. Alice wants to prove that the decryption of these ciphertexts all results in a.

Comment: Do these multiple texts a) all use the same $(pk, dk)$ pair with multiple $(u_i,v_i,vk_i)$ triples or b) use multiple $(pk_i,dk_i,u_i,v_i,vk_i)$ 5-tuples?

Comment: Yes. These ciphertexts all use the same (pk,dk) pair.

Answer (score 3):

Batch verification is straightforward in this case. Given $n$ signatures $(u_i,v_i,vk_i)$ for $1\le i\le n$, the same $x$ and $z$ value can be used to verify all $n$ signatures, by multiplying together the left and right hand sides of the verification equations thus:
$$pk^xA\stackrel ?= g^z$$
$$\left(\prod_i u_i\right)^x\prod_i B_i\stackrel ?=\left(\prod_i\left(\frac{v_i}{vk_i}\right)\right)^z.$$
This requires only 4 modular exponentiations and $3(n-1)$ multiplications rather than $2(n+1)$ modular exponentiations and $n$ multiplications. Clearly if the individual checks hold, then the composite check must also hold.

Comment: thx！May I know which paper contains the security analysis of this algorithm? It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: I think the paper [Can DSA be improved?](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0053426) from Eurocrypt 1994 is the ur-source for this observation.